# Need simple help about css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to learn bootstrap,I get what this `@media`,and `col-md-10` etc. represent, I inspected some pages and stumbled upon something like this.

`@media (min-width: 768px)
.col-10\@md {
    width: 83.33333%;
}`

Can someone please explain me what is that `\@md` part cant find anywhere and dont know even how to search for it?

Thank you.

Comment: \ is for escaping special characters in css. One can use the Unicode code point as well

Comment: Have a site or jsfiddle we can look at?

Comment: link of the page?! I just checked their source code and that is not the source code they have at v3.3.7 and v4 alpha v6.

Comment: ok that's not css, that's `less`. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/less/grid.less

Comment: I found it here  https://www.helpscout.net/blog/#most-recent  under section class blog-featured

Comment: @AleksandarJeftic it is not bootstrap, should be `less` with customized grid system similar to bootstrap.

Comment: so that `@md` is some sort of custom variable they made in `less` ?

Comment: I don't think it's Less at all. I think they're simply escaping the at symbol `@` because it's a special character in CSS and it's simply a part of they're naming convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking at appears to be a naming convention used by the site's developers.

The at sign `@` is a special character in a CSS file. To use it literally, without invoking it's special-ness, it needs to be escaped with a backslash `\`.

Demo CSS with escaped `@`:

```css
.an-\@example {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div class="an-@example"></div>
```

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

- [CSS Specification: Characters and Case](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters).